# How to verify if a graph has crossing edges in networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I am creating a genetic algorithm to solve the traveling salesman problem using python and networkx. And I'm adding a condition to converge to a satisfactory solution: the path must not have crossing edges. I wonder if there's a quick function in networkx to verify if the graph has crossing edges or, at least, want to know if it's possible to create one.

The graph is created with a list of points (`path`), each point has a coordinate in x, and a coordinate in y. The sequence of points index the path to tour. I created an object `nx.Graph()` like below:

```
        G = nx.Graph()
        for i in range(len(path)):
            G.add_node(i, pos=(path[i].x, path[i].y))
            
        for i in range(len(path)-1):
            G.add_edge(i, i+1)
        G.add_edge(len(path)-1, 0)
```

One example of converging not optimal solution:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2XJc.png]

printing out the points with `nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')`:

```
{0: (494, 680), 1: (431, 679), 2: (217, 565), 3: (197, 581), 4: (162, 586), 5: (90, 522), 6:(138, 508), 7: (217, 454), 8: (256, 275), 9: (118, 57), 10: (362, 139), 11: (673, 89), 12: (738, 153), 13: (884, 119), 14: (687, 542), 15: (720, 618), 16: (745, 737), 17: (895, 887), 18: (902, 574), 19: (910, 337), 20: (823, 371), 21: (601, 345), 22: (608, 302), 23: (436, 294), 24: (515, 384), 25: (646, 495)}
```

Here is an article supporting the condition of convergence:
http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-tsp

Comment: This looks like a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_line_segment_intersection

Comment: I would use shapely to find the interesecting lines.

Comment: Related question: [How check if there is intersection of any two edges given the fixed nodes positions, assuming the edges are drawn as straight lines with networkx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65157139/how-check-if-there-is-intersection-of-any-two-edges-given-the-fixed-nodes-positi)

Comment: @fabricio Brum, if still available can you fix/re-upload your image to stackoverflow (T2XJc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first reading was the same as [@AveragePythonEngineer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16293191/averagepythonenjoyer). Normally in the travelling salesman problem, and graph theory in general, we don't care too much about the positions of the vertices, only the distances between them. And I thought you might be confusing the **drawing** of a graph with the graph (it's just one realization of infinite possible drawings). So while you can draw a planar graph with crossing edges if you wish (like your example), the point is that you *could* draw it in the plane.

On re-reading your question, I think you're actually introducing the 'no crossing paths' as a constraint. To put it another way using the jargon: the path must not be self-intersecting. If that's right, then I think [this question in GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423351/identifying-self-intersections-in-linestring-using-shapely) will help you. It uses [`shapely`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html), a very useful tool for 2D geometric questions. From the first answer:

> [Check out] [`.is_simple`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.is_simple)
>
> > Returns True if the feature does not cross itself.

```py
from shapely.wkt import loads
l = loads('LINESTRING (9603380.577551289 2719693.31939431, 9602238.01822002 2719133.882441244, 9601011.900844947 2718804.012436028, 9599670.800095448 2718931.680117098, 9599567.204161201 2717889.384686942, 9600852.184025297 2721120.409265322, 9599710.80929024 2720511.270897166, 9602777.832940497 2718125.875545334)')
print(l.is_simple) # False
```

If you're looking to solve the problem from scratch then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4876249/3381305) to a similar question, but in a different framework, has some interesting leads, especially the [Bentley–Ottmann algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm), which might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree with your assessment.

Comment: Solving it through the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm seems the ideal way. I will adapt the graph to shapely and compare them. Thank you very much! For curiosity, my algorithm is in https://github.com/onofabricio/caixeiroViajante. (It is in Portuguese)  Just run the main.py script and solve for random points

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure, whether it suits your problem, but it seems to me that it is related to the [planarity of a graph.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph)

You can check whether a graph is planar with:

```
nx.is_planar(G)
```

which returns `True`, if it is. [See the documentation.](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.planarity.is_planar.html#networkx.algorithms.planarity.is_planar)

Comment: I actually tried this before and it always returned True, I don't know why.